# Eclipse RCP: How to configure the Perspective Menu?

Tags: menu, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I need to have total control of the perspective menu.

I already hacked into the platform to disable the CONTEXT menu:

```
private void disablePerspectiveToolbarMenu() {
    PerspectiveBarManager perspectiveBarManager =
        ((WorkbenchWindow) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()).getPerspectiveBar();
    if (perspectiveBarManager!=null){
        ToolBar toolBar = perspectiveBarManager.getControl();
        Listener[] listeners = toolBar.getListeners(SWT.MenuDetect);
        if (listeners != null){
            for (Listener listener : listeners){
                toolBar.removeListener(SWT.MenuDetect, listener);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**But i need also to control the default contents of the PERSPECTIVE MENU**. There is one option that is always present that gives access to a Perspective List Shell. I need to remove that option from the menu.

It's a shame that the perspective menu is totally out of user control. I just need to have the perspectives added to the menu, and nothing more!

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I opened a "feature request" on eclipse site (few weeks ago) over the PerspectiveBar's lack of control. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 potential options to get rid of Other:

1. Set the
   `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_OTHER_IN_PERSPECTIVE_MENU`
   preference to `false` in your RCP app. This can be done by including a `plugin_customization.ini` file with your product definition.
2. Patch the workbench in your RCP app.
   Have a look at
   `org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveBarNewContributionItem`
   and
   `org.eclipse.ui.actions.ContributionItemFactory.PERSPECTIVES_SHORTLIST`
3. Don't include the default
   perspective bar in your RCP app. 
   Instead, create a perspective bar
   using org.eclipse.ui.menus, a
   toolbar, and the openPerspective
   command.

Comment: Thanks! I could not make it work through the plugin_customization.ini. But added it to my other initializations: PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_OTHER_IN_PERSPECTIVE_MENU, false);

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and the solution did not work as I expected it. Finally I found my mistake.

To set the property in the plugin_customization.ini I tried:

```
    org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_OTHER_IN_PERSPECTIVE_MENU=false
```

but this is not the correct notation!!! Please see the correct solution I added finally to the plugin_customization.xml

```
    org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_OTHER_IN_PERSPECTIVE_MENU=false
```

**So the name of the interface or the class specifying the property ist not part of the notation!**